# how to change url pattern in jsp

Tags: java, php, .htaccess, jsp

i'm new to jsp, and i need to map url to a new pattern, here is what i'm doing in php is change the url pattern from .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]+)$ go.php?code=$1
```

so the result of the url will be www.site.com/{XXXX}

after that i can got the value of XXXX by GET request.

how i can do the same thing in jsp? 
i tried some cases by modify the pattern in web.xml file

```
<servlet>
<description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
<display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
<servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>thServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/s/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but to get the value of " * ", i need to parse the requested url.

```
request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf("/")
```

so my question is how to get the value of request directly like in php

Comment: you need parameter that are passed by GET method ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Comment: `String codeParam = request.getParameter("code");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using URLRewriteFilter http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ for that requirement. First add a Maven dependency if you are using Maven as Dependency Management:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Or, add [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/files/urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar) to your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Then modify your web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

And finally add a `urlrewrite.xml` in WEB-INF folder.
Then you can add rules to that file as needed (Example taken from http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/). More examples can be found [here](http://cdn.rawgit.com/paultuckey/urlrewritefilter/master/src/doc/manual/4.0/guide.html#urlabs).

```
<rule>
    <from>^/tidy/page$</from>
    <to>/old/url/scheme/page.jsp</to>
</rule>
<outbound-rule>
    <from>^/old/url/scheme/page.jsp$</from>
    <to>/tidy/page</to>
</outbound-rule>
```

Any incoming requests for `/tidy/page` will be transparently forwarded to `/old/url/scheme/page.jsp`.

So in your case the rule will be something like this:

```
<rule>
    <from>^([A-Z]+)$</from>
    <to>go.php?code=$1</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, note that the JSP site (go.jsp or whatever) could  be vulnerable if you pass through the request parameter without checking first. I don't known what you do with that parameter in your JSP. More information on that can be found on the [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org) site (Open Web Application Security Project).

Comment: Of course, i will check the parameter and the value of that parameter before doing anything, and thanks for providing me OWASP site.